# How can I avoid this error with setenv in C?

Tags: c, gcc, posix, irix

First disclosure: I am not much of a C programmer.  I am trying to compile a  set of C and Fortran codes with much pedigree, using a Makefile to generate an executable for engineering computation.  I am using gcc 4.7.1 on sgi Irix (6.5.30). During compilation of the main program, first I get  a warning on 'Implicit declaration of function 'setenv'. Subsequently, after generating all the objective 'o' files, the compilation ends with an error :

> ld32: Error 33: Unresolved data symbol "setenv"

Commenting out the single line where the 'setenv' is defined allows the compilation to succeed and generate the executable file. However the line with setenv is crucial to the program.

This led me to write a test code and confirm the same problem :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   setenv("FILE","/usr/bin/example.c",50);
   printf("File = %s\n", getenv("FILE"));
   return 0;
}
```

Based on all the suggestions I have found while googling here on stack exchange and other sites, I tried including different headers like

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE
```

and

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before any #define statements. I have also tried compiling with `-std=c99` as well as `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE` and `-D_GNU_SOURCE` with no luck.

I have also tried compiling the test program with Irix's native C compiler (cc and c99) and I get the same error:

> Unresolved text symbol 'setenv'

Can someone please provide a helping hand on what else I should look for in my system and or environment variables in order to resolve this error?

Comment: related: on iOS I had the same issue: `putenv` not found.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  that's because iOS is based on BSD.  The BSD function is `setenv`, `putenv` was the SVR4 equivalent.  It's historical.

Comment: ah, could have been an interesting Q&A too :)

Answer (score 6):

It indeed looks like IRIX libc does not support the `setenv()` command. You will have to rewrite it with `putenv()` like this:

```
putenv("FILE=/usr/bin/example.c");
```

See also the [IRIX putenv() manpage](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/IRIX/man3/putenv.3c.html%20%22IRIX%20putenv%20manpage). Looking for `setenv()` there does not show any hits, so I assume, this function is missing (note: IRIX 6.5.30 is from 2006)

Comment: btw. I've found [this source code](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/proc/setenv.c.html) for `setenv()`. Maybe it's easier to implement it than to change the code

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Especially if you really need the `overwrite` flag, this is a good option!

Comment: ok, thank you. I see that source code for setenv(). so what do I need to do now? put that source code in a  separate file and compile it together with the main or add it to the end of main? do I need to declare or prototype it? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @KaushikMallick If you do _not_ need the `overflow` parameter (it is rarely useful indeed), just use putenv. Otherwise, you can c&p the code for setenv and place it right before your main function, that should do.

Comment: ok great. can do. the original code that I want to work is: setenv("CCX_JOBNAME_GETJOBNAME",jobnamec,1); how do replace that with putenv(). thanks a lot again.

Comment: Note that if you use `putenv()`, you need to worry about whether any `setenv()` implementation you found works with the built-in `putenv`.  Where you have a fixed value (string literal) for the file name, using `putenv()` is simple enough.  If the value being set varies, you have to worry about whether your memory management is correct.  The stqandard `putenv()` does not make a copy of the string you pass to it — that string has got to survive unmangled for long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Setting or changing an environment variable has been problematic in the past.  With a fixed memory area for the environment block, various solutions have been used.  These have included chaining memory fragments, and using `realloc`(3).  There had been no standard way of changing the environment block, even now C99 specifically excludes `putenv`(3), and does not mention `setenv`(3).

POSIX includes both [`setenv`(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/setenv.html) and [`putenv`(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/putenv.html), which do a similar job.  The standard does state, however, that `setenv`(3) is the preferred function:

*"There was considerable debate as to whether the System V putenv() function or the BSD setenv() function should be required as a mandatory function. The setenv() function was chosen because it permitted the implementation of the unsetenv() function to delete environmental variables, without specifying an additional interface. The putenv() function is available as an XSI extension."*

Neither are thread-safe.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093392/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-iso-c99-standard-c-without-setenv) might be a duplicate, although it specifically mentions C99 rather than `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you, my problem is solved!
I replaced

```
setenv("CCX_JOBNAME_GETJOBNAME",jobnamec,1)
```

in my original main C program
with

```
putenv("CCX_JOBNAME_GETJOBNAME=jobnamec")
```

and I was able to compile the codes to completion to create the final executable.